# The usage of it in sentences

Tags: grammar

It’s been always confusing to me whether some widely used sentences that have “it” in them were grammatically correct.        “The winner takes it all” is this sentence grammatically correct?                 Why is “it” used in that sentence? Shouldn’t it be “The winner takes  all”? Or is there a change in meaning by including the “it” in it?                                                                                                   And there’s this sentence that I have seen some students use when asking the teacher if they could borrow a textbook “Do you have a textbook I can bring it home?” In this case, is it grammatical to use the word “it”? Should it be changed to “bring home”?                        It was kind of awkward to me to say that :/                                    Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Winner takes all" is a common idiom meaning there are no prizes for 2nd or lower places in some competition, often metaphorically applied to situations that aren't organized contests, for example a competition between two companies.

I've never heard "the winner takes it all", but it is perfectly grammatical. It implies we've previously discussed what "it" is and "it" is something it would also be conceivable to take only part of.

As for "Do you have a textbook I can bring it home?" this is not standard. I'd say either "Do you have a textbook I can bring home?" or "Do you have a textbook? Can I bring it home?"

Comment: Thanks you’ve clarified my confusion

Comment: You've *never* heard "The winner takes it all"? Really? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92cwKCU8Z5c

Comment: @RegDwigнt, (a), no I wasn't aware of that song. (b) it wasn't written by a native English speaker.